# Netbeans and SVN Issue

Tags: svn, netbeans

All,

I am using Netbeans IDE and connected it to Subversion. I have two folders in my netbeans project.

```
library
 --> Zend
```

I downloaded the latest Zend framework and want to update the local Zend Folder. I tried multiple options like the following and SVN complains that it's not a working copy.

1. Replace Zend Folder with new Zend folder and committing changes. - Didn't work. SVN says it's not a working copy and i have to do update from svn.
2. Delete Zend Folder locally and put new one. Still doesn't work. SVN says it's not a working copy and i have to update from svn.

How do i solve this dilemma?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you delete a folder, you're also deleting the .svn folder which tells SVN that the folder is a working copy folder.

Delete/replace the files, but not the directories.

Or delete the folder, commit, add the new folder, and commit again.